# Financial Quarters from date

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, date-time, date-modified

I have looked around for other solutions to this issue using the =ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0) code.

However I am not using the standard dates for Quarters

Q1 - 02-Feb/03-may
Q2 - 04-May/02-Aug
Q3 - 03-Feb/01-Nov
Q4 - 02-Nov/31-Jan

I know that I could offset the Quarter from the =ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0) value however this would include the 1st/2nd/3rd of the month in the wrong quarter.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The math doesn't get prettier, but what you are actually doing with your quarters is to shift all date's back by a month and then back by the number of days before the first sunday of that month.

So to calculate the number of days in the previous month, we use: `=DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);1)-1)`. This takes the first of this month and subtracts one day and then lets Excel calculate the day-part of that date, which is the number of days in that month.

Next, to shift the number of days back until sunday, we'll subtract a week and add the daynumber of that week, starting with 1 at monday's using: `=WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);1);2)`

Finally, after shifting the days, we can compute the quarter just like you suggested: `=ROUNDUP(MONTH(A1)/3,0)`.

Now, if you have a date in A1, you can calculate the "Philip Kennedy"-quarter with (and I'll indent it for clarity):

```
=ROUNDUP(                                           // Regular "roundup for quarter
    MONTH(
        A1-                                         // Take the date, but subtract...
        DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);1)-1)-          // ...the days of last month...
        7 + WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);1);2)   // ...and the weekdays before sunday
    ) 
/ 3;0 )`.
```

Or in one line: `=ROUNDUP( MONTH(A1-DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);1)-1)-7+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1);MONTH(A1);1);2))/3,0)`

Comment: =ROUNDUP(MONTH(D2-DAY(DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2),1)-1)-7+WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(D2),MONTH(D2),1),2))/3,0)  It was a 0 instead of a 1 but works perfectly thanks a lot